# Exporting table from MySQL and importing to Google sheet

Tags: java, mysql, excel, mysql-workbench, google-sheets-api

I want to export one table from MySQL to a Google sheet. I am working in Java environment and MySQL Workbench. Is there anyway to achieve this?

Suppose I have a table by the name `Student` which has following columns:

Student

```
------------------------------------------------------
      ID                  NAME                RollNo.
------------------------------------------------------

       1                  abc                   111
       2                  xyz                   222
       3                  lmn                   333
------------------------------------------------------
```

I just want to export ID and NAME columns from the above table to a google sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at `=IMPORTRANGE()`

It might be what you're looking for. [Here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en) is the documentation.

I use it quite often to pull an SQL database into Google sheets.